# How can I calculate numbers (for example) from 1 - 10 with the next number. (1+2+3+4+ ...)

Tags: c#

Does it have a shorter way than doing something like this:

```
int[] Summe = new int[6];
Summe[0] = 1;
Summe[1] = 2;
Summe[2] = 3;
Summe[3] = 4;
Summe[4] = 5;
Summe[5] = 6;

Console.WriteLine(Summe[0] + Summe[1] + Summe[2] + Summe[3] + Summe[4] + Summe[5]);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Why not put into a while loop? First, check if the sum is less than ten, than n++ to increment by one.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Sum());`

Comment: If im putting Enumerable into my code, i get: CS0103

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Wow thanks! But i have 2 questions:
1: Why do i need to add that manually and not automatically from visual studio
2: Can you explain me, whats Enumerable.Range.Sum is?

Answer (score 1):

OR from high school

```
// sum of integers from 1 to n
int SumNaturalNumbers(int n)
{
  return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```

Formula for the general algebraic series starting from a and difference between terms d ([Arithmetic progression and series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression))

```
sum = n / 2 * (2 * a + (n - 1) * d)
```

Comment: this will overflow for big numbers. To avoid this you need to do:  `if (n % 2 == 0) return n / 2 * (n + 1); else return n * ((n + 1) / 2);`

Comment: @bolov Right you are.  It wasn't a great question but I couldn't leave all those "here's how to iterate" answers dangling there, as if they were the best or - as asked for - shortest approach.

Comment: completely agree. Those loops (either explicit or linq) are ... let's say not great. And what I mentioned becomes a problem only for big number, so your answer is ok. I just wanted to mention this for anyone reading to be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Enumerable.Sum()` method which computes the sum of a sequence of numeric values and `Enumerable.Take()` which returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence.

```
Console.WriteLine(Summe.Take(10).Sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a foreach loop may be helpful here, since you're dealing with an array. Also, you can define your array on one line.

```
int[] Summe = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

int total = 0;

foreach (int number in Summe)
{
    total += number;
}
Console.WriteLine(total);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this process by simply putting this operation into a while loop.

```
int i = 0; // tell your program what 'i' should be upon first running the code

while (i < 10) // if 'i' is less than 10, run this block of code. You can change 10 to anything you want
{
    Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);

    i++; // increment
}
```

This will print each number individually, but you want to calculate the sum of every number, so you could do something like this:

```
{  
    public static void Main() 
{
    int  j, sum = 0;

    Console.Write("\n\n");
    Console.Write("Find the sum of first 10 natural numbers:\n");
    Console.Write("----------------------------------------------");
    Console.Write("\n\n");
    
    Console.Write("The first 10 natural number are :\n");
     for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + j; // add the previous number to the current one
        Console.Write("{0} ",j);    
    }
    Console.Write("\nThe Sum is : {0}\n", sum);
  }
}
```

The above code prints the sum of the first 10 natural numbers. I added some additional lines simply to make the program more legible. Again, you can change the number 10 to whatever number you want.